# Air iOS Flash, StageQuality.LOW doesn't seem to work

Tags: ios, performance, flash, optimization, air

I've read few articles about optimizing Flash performance on Air for iOS and many of them suggested to use StageQuality.LOW mode. But it seems Air(I'm using 3.6) doesn't allow you to use StageQuality.LOW, it must be either HIGH or BEST quality.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to turn it LOW quality mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there is a difference in performance. StageQuality the difference in rendering performance such as bitmaps or textfield. StageQuality Lower Not applying antialiasing vector graphics, bitmap graphics without does not draw smoothly. Higher quality settings produce better rendering of scaled bitmaps. also, higher quality settings are computationally more expensive. In particular, when rendering scaled video, using higher quality settings can reduce the frame rate.

What are you doing the work? If you use the BitmapData, recommend as follows.

AIR 3.3 later added a new featured drawing method called [drawWithQuality](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#drawWithQuality%28%29), which allows you to draw assets at a quality that is independent from the stage quality setting used in your app.

In the past, the stage quality would have to be modified to change the quality of BitmapData.draw. BitmapData. drawWithQuality is an extension of BitmapData.draw that adds an optional parameter to specify the quality of vector rendering.

```
function drawWithQuality(source: IBitmapDrawable, matrix:Matrix=null, colorTransform: ColorTransform =null, blendMode:String=null, clipRect:Rectangle=null, smoothing:Boolean=false, quality:String=null): void
```

Following are the supported quality values:

> - StageQuality.LOW
> - StageQuality.MEDIUM
> - StageQuality.BEST
> - StageQuality.HIGH_8X8_LINEAR
> - StageQuality.HIGH_16X16
> - StageQuality.HIGH_16X16_LINEAR

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Using Air for iOS, I can change the stage quality to HIGH or BEST but it seems it won't allow me to set the stage quality to LOW or MEDIUM. When trying to set it to LOW or MEDIUM, it simply stays at HIGH or BEST.

Answer (score 1):

It does work it just always shows up as HIGH in the AIR simulator. Will change on actual device. Bitmaps will smooth even in low quality in GPU mode as well.

Comment: That's nice to know. I'm going to try. Thanks